# ViewPager android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-viewpager

есть ViewPager с картинками. Можно ли как то сделать так чтобы он как ViewFlipper (Слайдер) по указоному интервалу времени переходил на следующию картинку

Answer (score 0):

Ответ отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/a/16494939/5892568 с использованием очереди Handler и запуском повторно на очереди

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
            if( position >= 4){
                position = 0;
            }else{
                position = position+1;
            }
            toBarPager.setCurrentItem(position, true);
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10000);
    }
};
```

Чистить на onPause()

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (handler!= null) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
}
```

И рестартовать onResume()

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10000);
}
```